# How to modify one's cursor through C++ Windows Console

Tags: c++, windows, windows-xp, mouse-cursor

I wish to create a new cursor to be used with my program. I want to make the cursor appear as a circle that I have already made, but I can't seem to get it to temporarily change to it when only using the game window, and I also can't get it to stay overtop of the normal cursor. Please, is there a way to change the cursor in c++ based on if it's over a certain window? The only methods I found used system commands, which are a security issues, and have not changed it back. I have had to go in and manually change the cursor back every time I finish with the program. Thanks in advance, and if you have any questions or I am unclear, please say so!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change the cursor in window by using [LoadCursorFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648392%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SetCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You will need to create `.ANI` file that describes the cursor, you can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANI_%28file_format%29).

Comment: The console window actually belongs to another process so calling `SetCursor` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the window's cursor when you create the window: see [Class Cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#class_cursor) and the `hCursor` member of the [WNDCLASS structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).